# How do I convert a callback to a generator?

Tags: ecmascript-6, generator, redux-saga

Consider the following code:

```
export function* listen(channel, event, action) {
    yield call(
        [LaravelEchoManager, LaravelEchoManager.registerListener],
        channel,
        event,
        (data) => {
            // yield data;
        },
    );
}
```

The LaravelEchoManager.registerListener method registers an event listener for the given channel and the given event and calls the callback `(data) => { ... }` for each message received.

How do I yield the received data?

Comment: You can’t. It would only be possible if `registerListener` returned a generator (which I doubt it does). Think about it : a generator yields back data to its **caller**. But you are not the caller of the callback, some other code is.

Comment: That makes sense to me. Currently I'm trying a workaround with Promises which resolve methods are stored outside of the Promise resolver so that I can invoke them within the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can but you have to `yield` something else. Like for example a promise:

```
export function* listen(channel, event, action) {
  yield call(() => new Promise(done => {
    LaravelEchoManager.registerListener(
      channel,
      event,
      (data) => {
        done(data);
      }
    );
  }));    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can cheat using this kind of trick:

```
let received = [];
let active; // set to false to stop listening
export function* listen(channel, event, action) {
    call(
        [LaravelEchoManager, LaravelEchoManager.registerListener],
        channel,
        event,
        (data) => {received[received.length] = data},
    );
    active = true; // start linstening
    while(active){
        while(received.length <= 0); // active wait
        yield received.shift();
    }
}
```

It answer the question, but I don't really advise to do this kind of thing.
Maybe you have to find another way to do your task.

Comment: This won't work. `while(received.length <= 0); ` is blocking. Nothing can be added to the array.

Comment: Ah yeah you're right. If you have not multi threading process it will never work.